# Use of singleton for SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am not 100% familiar with the concept of using `singleton` for additional frameworks. For example, what is the difference between the following two function calls for `SDWebImage`, when I should use which. Some small examples would be great

```
SDWebImageManager().saveImageToCache(myImg, forURL: myUrl)
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().saveImageToCache(myImg, forURL: myUrl)
```

Comment: maybe making an extension of UIImage will be better no ? So you can create a method to save image in cache with a specific url passed as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- when I should use which:

You should always use

```
 SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().saveImageToCache(myImg, forURL: myUrl)
   <=> let sharedInstance = SDWebImageManager.sharedManager();
           sharedInstance.saveImageToCache(myImg, forURL: myUrl)
```

- Why:
  SDWebImageManager.sharedManager() means: call method `sharedManager` of class `SDWebImageManager` to get an instance of Class `SDWebImageManager`,

then you call `saveImageToCache(...)` to call method `saveImageToCache` of that instance.

- Sample from [SDWebImage repository](https://github.com/orta/ImageCachingExamples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sharedManager)

Comment: I am abit unclear as to why I should always use the sharedManager. I guess it makes sense to only use one instance. Would I encounter some bug down the track if I didnt used the sharedManager way? ( I like to learn by knowing what would go wrong for the wrong case)

Comment: First: saveImageToCache is an instance method. So if you need a same result , you should call that method with same instance (that why we need sharedManager).  
Second: learn to use your upvote button if people anwser helped you , lol

Answer (score 2):

1. Create new instance of `SDWebImageManager` everytime you call.
2. Use same instance of `SDWebImageManager` - that was created and setup only one time and always ready for you to use.

Comment: Looking at Dinh's answer, I should always used the sharedManager right? What is wrong with creating SDWebImageManager every time if I did it the "wrong" way

Comment: nothing's wrong here, it depends on you and on your purpose.